# Highcharts: xxx.animate doesn't work correctly when objects are replaced each other more than once

Tags: javascript, highcharts

The below code doesn't work correctly when I click the button more than once. I found the temporary solution is to call `chart.destroy()` and `chart = Highcharts.chart(...)` to reset the internal states. But I want to know the right solution because that's just a temporary measure and it won't solve the actual cause of the problem. Please anyone can help me?

```
var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', options);

var update = function () {
  var points = chart.series[0].points;
  chart.series[0].setData([points[0].y, points[1].y + 200]);
};

var rotate = function () {
  var points = chart.series[0].points,
      ticks = chart.xAxis[0].ticks;

  var sortedPoints = points.slice();
  sortedPoints.sort(function(a,b){
    return b.y - a.y;
  });

  points.forEach(function(point, i){
    sortedPoints.forEach(function(sPoint, j){
      if (point === sPoint){

        points[i].graphic.animate({
          x: points[j].shapeArgs.x
        });

        points[i].dataLabel.animate({
          y: points[j].dataLabel.y
        });

        ticks[i].label.animate({
          y: ticks[j].label.xy.y
        });
      }
    });
  });
};

document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
    update();
    rotate();
}, false);
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/Shinohara/dscvwrxu/22/

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to reset the internal states. You can relay on current and initial values:

```
var rotate = function() {
    var points = chart.series[0].points,
        index,
        ticks = chart.xAxis[0].ticks;

    var sortedPoints = points.slice();
    sortedPoints.sort(function(a, b) {
        return b.y - a.y;
    });

    points.forEach(function(point, i) {
        sortedPoints.forEach(function(sPoint, j) {
            if (point === sPoint) {
                index = j;

                if (points[i].animated) {
                    points[i].animated = false;

                    j = i;
                } else {
                    points[i].animated = true;
                }

                points[i].graphic.animate({
                    x: points[j].shapeArgs.x
                });

                points[i].dataLabel.animate({
                    y: points[index].dataLabel.y
                });

                ticks[i].label.animate({
                    y: ticks[j].label.xy.y
                });
            }
        });
    });
};
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/jfd0vuy8/

Comment: Thanks ppotaczek always! I think your code don't solve this question and I wrote my second question. If you have time, I'd really appreciate it if you could give me your opinion.

Answer (score 0):

@ppotaczek Your live demo rotates bars infinitely when I click the button more than once. In this case, what I want is the code which rotates bars for the first time only. The below is my intention.

```
State1:    Cat1=1000, Cat2=900  # Current rank is 1st:Cat1 and 2nd:Cat2
Interval1: Cat2+=200 and rotate bars between state1 and state2
State2:    Cat1=1000, Cat2=1100 # Current rank is 1st:Cat2 and 2nd:Cat1
Interval2: Cat2+=200 and don't rotate bars between state2 and state3
State3:    Cat1=1000, Cat2=1300 # Current rank is 1st:Cat2 and 2nd:Cat1
```

I think the reason why your live demo rotates bars between state2 and state3 is `update()` also rotates bars.

```
// This function unintentionally rotates bars for the second time.
var update = function() {
    var points = chart.series[0].points;
    chart.series[0].setData([points[0].y, points[1].y + 200]);
};
```

I want to put bars from largest to smallest. And I don't want to rotate bars when the rank is not changed. Do you have any good solution?

Comment: Hi Teruki Shinohara, Sorry I misunderstood your question. Please check this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7a5uc4db/ and let me know if everything is ok.

Comment: Thanks ppotaczek!! It seems like that your code is just a little wrong. When I put three or more bars, the dataLabels move wrong positions. Code to reproduce -> https://jsfiddle.net/Shinohara/jsba0k63/2/ Real data (which has many bars) https://ts-3156.github.io/chasingchart/src/index.html I think all I have to do is to write many if statements according to a number of bars. However, I'd rather reinitialize the chart object than write many if statements. I think another solution is to fix the behavior of dataLabels in Highcharts because only dataLabels of the three do strange behavior.

Comment: Can I get your opinion?

Comment: Hi Teruki Shinohara, Yes, the behavior of dataLabels is different than the other elements and difficult to predict. I think it will be best if you create custom data labels: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/81zc297s/ It seems to be the most stable solution in your case.